# Inverse trigonometric functions which returns a complex number- depends on angular mode or not?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

When the parameter of inverse trig functions is out range, the result is complex number.

Is this result should be converted according to the angular mode of the calculator?

For example:
asin(90) = 1.5707 - 1.0232i [radians]

In DEG mode: Is the result should be: 90 - 297.5i, or  to stays in radians?

I checked it out with few scientific calculators, but I didn't found any uniformity.

Thanks to all respondents!

Comment: Usually when we deal with complex numbers in trig, we assume the angle to be in radians. calculus related problems with trig require the angle to be in radians. Euler's famous equation $e^{{i\theta}}={cos\theta+isin\theta}$ works with radians.

Comment: It make a sense, thanks a lot!   
I accepted this answer :)